# Unix: Using sed remove part of each line

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I am trying to remove the Who: ,What:  ,When: ,Where: and the proceeding space from each line in a text file. Below is a example:

```
Who: Tester1+Password
What: Authentication Success
When: Tues March 20, 2015 08:15:02 UTD
Where: 198.192.1.2
```

Comment: is there other starting word or only these 4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove anything upto first `:`, then you can do:

```
sed -re 's/(^[^:]+: )(.*)/\2/' file
Tester1+Password
Authentication Success
Tues March 20, 2015 08:15:02 UTD
198.192.1.2
```

As Glenn suggested we can avoid capture groups completely by removing the portion we don't need.

```
sed 's/[^:]\+: //' file
```

Comment: You don't need to capture the 2nd bit: `sed 's/[^:]\+: //' file` -- in general, question whether you ever need to capture `(.*)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `cut` to exclude the first space-separated field:

```
cut -d " " -f 2- file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/^[^ ]* *//' YourFile
```

assuming only these 4 word are possible and as your sample

Answer (score 1):

Put the pattern which matches What, where, when , who inside a capturing group followed by a colon. Then replace the matched chars with an empty string. Add `i` flag at the last if you want do a case-insensitive match.

```
$ sed 's/^Wh\(ere\|en\|at\|o\):[[:blank:]]*//' file
Tester1+Password
Authentication Success
Tues March 20, 2015 08:15:02 UTD
198.192.1.2
```

For general case, you could use

```
sed 's/^[^[:blank:]]\+[[:blank:]]\+//' file
```